# Handle the case where getExtras returns null in the android cart

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, onrestoreinstancestate

I have a ExpandableListView in my cart, Im loading items to my cart using ExpandableListAdapter and cart activity. when an item is added to the cart i can display it but once i change the activity and go back to the cart, cart has become empty it shows the added item as empty. how can i hold the value in my cart.

I read about use of `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`but im bit confused about how to use it exactly. below i have shown my code. can anyone help me with this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    public class ShoppingCartActivity extends Activity {

    ProductAdapter mCartList;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    List<String> listDataHeaderPrice;
    List<String> listDataHeaderQty;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    private ExpandableListView mExpandableList;
    String description;
    String price;
    String quantity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);

        quantity = getIntent().getStringExtra("quantity");
        price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");
        description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");

        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add(description);
        myList.add(quantity);
        myList.add(price);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                        android.R.color.transparent)));
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        mCartList = new ProductAdapter(this, listDataHeader,
                listDataHeaderPrice, listDataHeaderQty, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(mCartList);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                        + " : "
                        + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataHeaderQty = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataHeaderPrice = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add(description);
        listDataHeaderQty.add(quantity);
        listDataHeaderPrice.add(price);

        // Adding child data
        List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
        description.add("The Shawshank");
        List<String> quantity = new ArrayList<String>();
        quantity.add("The Shawshank");
        List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
        price.add("The Shawshank");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), description);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeaderQty.get(0), quantity);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeaderPrice.get(0), price);
        // Header, Child
        // data

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        mExpandableList.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width
                - GetPixelFromDips(10));
    }

    public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
        // Get the screen's density scale
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
        return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.slide_out_right);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SearchResultsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0); //added his

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.slide_out_left);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_cart:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ShoppingCartActivity.class);

startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.slide_out_left);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

in my 2nd activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        // get the action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        txtQuery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> once i change the activity and go back to the cart, cart has become
>   empty it shows the added item as empty

Start next Activity using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` to get data back.

Also call `setResult(resultCode)` from Activity which started using `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: Cart should be always access from anywhere. its in my action bar in every activity screen. so do i need to use this in all the activities in my application?

Comment: @JohnDavid: Dear first try to fix current issue then we will look for others.

Comment: @JohnDavid: what problem getting when using startActivityForResult?

Comment: can u check my updated question, when i use this, this doesnt make any change

Comment: @JohnDavid: call `setResult(RESULT_OK);` inside onBackPressed method of second Activity

Comment: yh that works now. when i go to 2nd activity there i have a cart button. when i press that then it shows null. how can i achive that

Comment: @JohnDavid: What you want to show on cart button click?

Comment: when i add the items to the cart it open up cart and show the added item. then i have search in my action bar. when i open that and go back (as u mentioned ealr) it shows the items inside the cart. I have cart button in action bar when i press that it open up the cart and show null in where i tems loaded ealrlr

Comment: @JohnDavid: then also start `ShoppingCartActivity` Activity as `startActivityForResult` ? and im also not getting your question.when click on  cart button in which activity you want to go and what  value is showing null?

Comment: i tried in a differnt way i have save the data in onSaveInstanceState bt when it comes to oncreat() it always go into onSaveInstanceState=null. so can u check this link n help me please.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625235/issue-with-use-of-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate/28625358#28625358

Comment: @JohnDavid: `onSaveInstanceState`  method not help you because this will work when any configuration change happen . i think use sharedpreferences for saving data and show back from sharedpreferences when come back from other activity

Comment: ok ill work with sharepreference and update u. thanks alot for ur help