# Issue with use of onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, onrestoreinstancestate

Im using the below code in my shopping cart activity. when i added the items to cart, it shows the items in the cart. but when i open another activity and go back to the cart it shows null. then i found use of `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.. even after i use this code it shows null. can anyone point out what have gone wrong in this code.

what im expecting by use of this code is when i added the items to cart it will save in onSaveInstanceState, and when i open the cart again then it will use onRestoreInstanceState and show the items on the cart.

```
    public class ShoppingCartActivity extends Activity {

        ProductAdapter mCartList;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        List<String> listDataHeaderPrice;
        List<String> listDataHeaderQty;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
        private ExpandableListView mExpandableList;
        String description;
        String price;
        String quantity;
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            savedInstanceState.putString("description", description);
            savedInstanceState.putString("price", price);
            savedInstanceState.putString("quantity", quantity);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
          // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.

          description = savedInstanceState.getString("description");
          quantity = savedInstanceState.getString("quantity");
          price = savedInstanceState.getString("price");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

            quantity = getIntent().getStringExtra("quantity");
            price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");
            description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");

            myList.add(description);
            myList.add(price);
            myList.add(quantity);


            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            getActionBar().setIcon(
                    new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                            android.R.color.transparent)));
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            mCartList = new ProductAdapter(this, listDataHeader,
                    listDataHeaderPrice, listDataHeaderQty, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(mCartList);

            // Listview Group click listener
            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: onSaveInstanceState  will be called at some point when your activity is being killed to reclaim resources. So it is not necessary to be called.

Comment: i want to call it so how to kill it?

Comment: You dont need to kill your activity. In case android need resources it will kill your activity and call onSaveInstanceState method to save what ever you want. But if you get back to your activity it will maintain all UI fields and variables. If you are calling finish on your activity before moving to another activity it will destroy your current activity.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState save all the data, but when i come to the activity next time then it becomes null, restore or oncreate methodes doesnt identify the values saved in the onSaveInstanceState, so finally it shows null

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is called every time you leave your current activity?

Comment: yes but code doenst go inside onRestoreInstanceState methode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71334/discussion-between-nauman-afzaal-and-john-david).

Answer (score 0):

I think onRestoreInstanceState is called after onStart and the code for refreshing your UI is in onCreate. So the data is probably there but you don't show it in the UI. Try updating your ListView/Adapter after the line       `price = savedInstanceState.getString("price");`

Comment: I added this, if (savedInstanceState != null) {.. when i reopen the activity then it goes to and print 2. is there a way to pass savedInstanceState to onCreate?